# How do I layer CSS opacity?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm attempting to create a particular hover effect in an HTML list purely with CSS. When hovering, the "background" `nav` element should be half opacity but the "foreground" `li` should be full opacity.

```css
nav {
  font-size:2.0em;
}
nav:hover {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Unfortunately the `li` hover appears to have picked up the half opacity, even though `opacity:1.0` has been specified.

Why is this happening and what am I missing?

Comment: can you explain little more ?

Comment: it won't work because your LI tag is inside the NAV, What I mean is Your NAV tag will be 50% opacity and then your LI tag will be 100% of that 50%. Meaning will stay the same.

Comment: When you set the `<nav>` to `opacity:.5`, you are setting the opacity to its children as well. You need to either specify transparency in your `background-color` (via `rgba()`) or provide a background that is not a child of the `<nav>`.

Comment: @SajadLfc What do you need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
nav {
  font-size:2.0em;
}
nav:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
nav:hover li {
  opacity:0.5;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**Edit**

About the "why" part:

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

And

> Computed value: the specified value, clipped in the range [0,1]

So if you set `opacity:0.5` to `<nav>`, all of its child will share the same opacity as a "base". And since `opacity` can only be in range [0,1], `<li>`s inside this `<nav>` can not have more *practical* opacity than 0.5.

Using `rgba` sets the background color of the `<nav>`, and `nav:hover li{opacity:0.5}` applies the transparency to each `<li>` itself, making it possible to target the specific `li:hover` for a different opacity.

Comment: Good, but I'm missing the 'why' in this answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm not quite sure what OP want exactly, so I'm just giving a guess (and SO snippet can't be demonstrated in comment). I'll update the "why" part with reference.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `rgba()` for background color because opacity affects child elements:

```
nav:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

See it here:

```css
nav {
  font-size:2.0em;
}
nav:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do also something like this:

```css
nav {
  font-size:2.0em;
  position: relative;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  z-index: -1;
}

nav:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This might work well for IE8 which doesn't support rgba, thank you